# User is not defined firebase

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, collections

I am trying to push an object into an array that is saved to a user in the "users" collection. I keep getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined on this line     db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {

The code

```
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "####",
    authDomain: "###.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "#",
    storageBucket: "#.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "#",
    appId: "1:####"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = firebase.auth()
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

</script>
<script>
  function savetodb() {
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
        const saveditems1 = doc.data().saveditems
        const ob = {
          Name:'Test',
          Price:'Test',
          Link:'https://www.test.com'
        }
saveditems1.push(ob)

    });
```

The user **is** logged in, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: i mean... nowhere in your (shown) code is `user` defined

Comment: While the user may be 'logged in' this does not define 'user' within the environment, as such, you must request the user from Firebase Auth to obtain the currently logged-in user. You are not doing this. Also, downvoting answers actually affects us negatively as this is our job to answer questions.

Comment: Should also mention that the user authentication is an async process and you should await for it to change by registering the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared user variable. Either declare it as follows:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
```

Or directly pass it as param if you don't need user object anywhere else:

```
.doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the user before using it.

```
 // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "####",
    authDomain: "###.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "#",
    storageBucket: "#.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "#",
    appId: "1:####"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = firebase.auth()
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

</script>
<script>
  function savetodb() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
        const saveditems1 = doc.data().saveditems
        const ob = {
          Name:'Test',
          Price:'Test',
          Link:'https://www.test.com'
        }
saveditems1.push(ob)

    });
```